# Find all appointments in specified period with Restrict

Tags: vba, filter, outlook, calendar, appointment

I'm trying to get all appointments in a calendar occurring between the 5th of this month and the 4th of next month (including appointments that happen on those days).

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
    Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oAppointments As Object
    Dim monthlyPats As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    'Set up date filter
    Dim sMth As Date
    Dim eMth As Date
    
    sMth = dhFirstDayInMonth() + 3 '4th of this month
    eMth = dhLastDayInMonth() + 4 '4th of next month
    
    Dim eDate As String
    eDate = "[End] < '" & eMth & "'"
    
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = "[Start] > '" & sMth & "'"
    
    'Restrict tasks based on date filters
    Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Portfolio analysis scheduler").Items.Restrict(eDate)
    Set monthlyPats = oAppointments.Restrict(sDate)

End Sub
```

The dhFirstDayInMonth() and dhLastDayInMonth() functions get the first and last day of the current month.

I have two events on the 4th January 2018, one is a recurrent event that lasts all day and the other is a standalone event that lasts all day.

Only the recurrent event pulls through. If I make both of them recurrent then they both get captured in monthlyPats which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that restricting items in outlook can be a nightmare, I made sure the IncludeRecurrences property was set to True and sorted by start date, this seemed to do the trick.

Also, I made the restriction string do both jobs at once, seems to be a bit more robust:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim allAppointments As Object
    Dim oAppointments As Object
    Dim monthlyPats As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    'Set up date filter
    Dim sMth As Date
    Dim eMth As Date

    sMth = dhFirstDayInMonth() + 3 '4th of this month
    eMth = dhLastDayInMonth() + 5 '5th of next month

    Dim rstDate As String
    rstDate = "[Start] > '" & sMth & "'" & " AND " & "[End] < '" & eMth & "'"

    'Restrict tasks based on date filters
    Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set allAppointments = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Portfolio analysis scheduler").Items
    allAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
    allAppointments.Sort "[Start]"

    Set monthlyPats = allAppointments.Restrict(rstDate)
    monthlyPats.IncludeRecurrences = True

End Sub
```