# Filtered outlook events' TypeName remain "Nothing"

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, outlook-2016

I'm running a macro on excel to populate a shared outlook calendar. The thing is, I have no problem to add appointments to the calendar, but when dates change I want to suppress old ones, to replace them by new events.
I have a code that is supposed to filter the items I want to suppress, but for some reason the TypeName of my Outlook events remains on "Nothing", and I can't figure out why.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kzPQ.png) is the test event in my calendar that needs to be suppressed.

Here is the code:

````
Sub SuppressOutlookEvents()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objAppointments As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objProperty As Outlook.UserProperty
    Dim OutlookStartTime, OutlookEndTime As Date
    Dim sFilter As Variant

    Worksheets("to_be_removed").Activate

    OutlookStartTime = DateValue("10-15-2019")

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    sFilter = "[Start] =  OutlookStartTime And [Subject] = 'Test'"

    Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Items.Find(sFilter)

    ```
    MsgBox (TypeName(objAppointment)) 'Here it displays "Nothing" 
    If Not TypeName(objAppointment) = "Nothing" Then
        objAppointment.Delete
    End If
    ```

    Set objAppointment = Nothing
    Set objAppointments = Nothing

End Sub
````

I don't know if the filter doesn't recognize the event or if it's for another reason...

EDIT: thanks to the answers, I finally have a working code:

```
Sub suppress_outlook_event(Optional row As Integer = 2)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAppointments As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objProperty As Outlook.UserProperty
    Dim OutlookStartTime, OutlookEndTime As Date
    Dim sFilter As Variant

    OutlookStartTime = Format("09/19/19" & " " & "8:00 AM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    o_title = "Example"
    sFilter = "[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & o_title & Chr(34)

    objAppointments.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True
    objAppointments.Items.Sort "[Start]"

    Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
    objAppointment.IncludeRecurrences = True

    If Not objAppointment.Count = 0 Then
        obj_count = objAppointment.Count
        For i = 1 To obj_count
            objAppointment(obj_count + 1 - i).Delete
        Next i
    End If

    Set objAppointment = Nothing
    Set objAppointments = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider evaluating Boolean expression `objAppointment Is Nothing` instead of evaluating the type name for a much simpler, faster, and more reliable null-object check. If the object `Is Nothing`, then the appointment wasn't found.

Comment: Looking into this still, but your immediate failure is that ` sFilter = "[Start] =  OutlookStartTime And [Subject] = 'Test'"` should at the least be ` sFilter = "[Start] =  " & OutlookStartTime & " And [Subject] = 'Test'"`. Otherwise its searching for a date that equals the literal text OutlookStartTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should like be closed as duplicate, however I've made the required updates to your code.

Key points when using Find or Restrict with Appointments.

1. Make sure IncludeRecurrences Property is set to True
2. Ensure date/time is formatted as shown below and is parsed as a string as opposed to supplied as an actual date/datetime value.

I'm a bit skeptical on how it will handle multiple appointments with the same subject and start date (if time is not supplied or conflicting appointments exist). Past experience indicates it will just return the first one. So it may be better to use the Restrict method and iterate through the returned item collection otherwise you'll run the risk of missing an appointment.

[Items.Restrict appointments in Outlook Calendar (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924078/items-restrict-appointments-in-outlook-calendar-vba)

```
Sub SuppressOutlookEvents()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objAppointments As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objProperty As Outlook.UserProperty
    Dim OutlookStartTime, OutlookEndTime As Date
    Dim sFilter As Variant

    Worksheets("to_be_removed").Activate

    OutlookStartTime = Format("9-24-2019 12:30PM", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    sFilter = "[Start] =  '" & OutlookStartTime & "' And [Subject] = 'test'"


    objAppointments.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True
    objAppointments.Items.Sort "[Start]"


    Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Items.Find(sFilter)


    MsgBox (TypeName(objAppointment)) 'Here it displays "Nothing"
    If Not TypeName(objAppointment) = "Nothing" Then
        objAppointment.Delete
    End If


    Set objAppointment = Nothing
    Set objAppointments = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The restrict Method worked very well, thank you! I'll update the post with the working solution.